# Searching the registry by data values then exporting them via batch

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to make a scrip that will search a root-key for a value's data then export all the results. I'm unsure how to export the results when using an `for` statement. I'm using the `pipe /s | find` to search for a value's data. Any advice or tips will be greatly appreciated!

**INFO about the key:**

*Rootkey:* HKLM | *Subkey:* Unkown (Changes per machine, start's with "\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\") | *Value:* ClassGUID | *Data:* {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

**Current attempt:**

```
@for %%I in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum" /v "ClassGUID" /s | find "{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"') do (reg export %%~I %~dp0export.txt)
```

---

*In previous attempt's*

Previously - I was trying to get the actual path of the `Subkey` after searching for it by the `value` & `data`. Because of limitations, the location is not part of the `DataType`. - Due to this, I'm now trying to *export* the search results. From there I can create a `variable` from it by searching the text document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example script is intended to set and output variables containing the Data from all string Values named `FriendlyName` under all registry keys which begin `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\` and which also contain Value Data including the GUID string, `{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}`.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('Set DeviceName[ 2^>Nul') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For /F "EOL= Delims=" %%A In ('Reg Query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum"^
 /S /F "{4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}" /D^|Find /I "Enum"'
) Do Set /A i+=1 & For /F "Skip=1 Tokens=2*" %%B In ('Reg Query "%%A"^
 /V "FriendlyName" 2^>Nul') Do Call Set DeviceName[%%i%%]=%%C
Set DeviceName[ 2>Nul
Pause
```

Comment: This code is brilliant! If I wish to add, Would there be a way to change example, `%DeviceName[1]%` to a `set Name=NewName` ..?

Comment: That's a nice one +1

Comment: Great script to get listed all disk drives (hard disks, USB memory sticks) ever plugged on a computer running Windows Vista or a newer Windows version.